# Would a redirect from "/" to "http://www.mydomain.com" (to add the www) delist a site?

Tags: 301-redirect, canonical-url, cname

I am taking over a site for a client, and their SERP is very low for no obvious reason. I found that there is a 301 that looks like this:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.mydomain.org/
```

When I look at the DNS, the base domain (`mydomain.org`) is used for all of the settings and there is the following record:

```
CNAME   www.mydomain.org   is an alias of mydomain.org   300
```

I would assume that the CNAME entry is enough to point `mydomain.org` to `www.domain.org` and that the 301 is unnecessary AND might be getting the site delisted.

Comment: "is an alias of"

Answer (score 1):

The CNAME is **not** sufficient for a redirect.  A DNS CNAME pointing to the same IP address will create duplicate content if the webserver is not configured to do the redirect.    In that situation, the same content on the website will be available under two different URLs:

- `http://mysite.example.com`
- `http://www.mysite.example.com`

Although Google is much better about dealing with this than it used to be, this is not my preferred setup for search engine optimization.   Users will be able to use both versions and different users may see different things in the browser URL bar.    When users create links to the site, their links will be to whichever version *they* chose.

Most webmasters will want to choose themselves whether or not their site uses the www or not.   The redirect that you found does exactly that.    Using such a redirect is very common practice.   My sites all do this redirect.   It will in no way contribute to SEO problems.  It is considered an SEO best practice.

Comment: Yes, the site is correctly being routed from non www to the www of the domain, and Webmaster Tools is not showing any duplicate content.

Comment: I just want to confirm that "Redirect 301 / http://www.mydomain.org/" is a typical redirect that doesn't cause any harm. I haven't really seen one with that same syntax.

Comment: With the `http://` in there like it is in your question, that is the common syntax.  Its from [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question : No, it is highly unlikely that a redirect to www would be responsible for delisting of a site.

Though to double check, use fetch as googlebot in Webmaster Tools and ensure the pages can be crawled okay. You can also do a site:search to see a general overview of the pages indexed. Not sure what you mean by "serp is low", but if you see the pages crawled and indexed okay then delisting isnt happening.

Comment: So just to be sure, Redirect 301 / http://www.mydomain.org/ is a typical redirect?

Comment: By "SERP is low" I mean that they are ranking on the 4th page of Google for a search term that has very good on-page SEO all over their website and that used to place them in the top 3 results. Google Webmaster Tools shows that the site is being indexed and no major errors, so I'm trying to figure out why this happening.

Comment: If it is a ranking issue and pages are still indexed then I would look for other reasons.